# Why is data not getting added on Recordset.Update in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

So I am trying to track changes made to a table in my database when a part gets moved from the "Open Date" category to the "End Date" category. I have already implemented a similar scheme for data updates, but for some reason I can't get it to work with this. As far as I can tell, there are no errors popping up. I have also confirmed that all of the RS! values are pulling up correctly.

Code:

```vb
Dim SQL as String
Dim rs As DAO.RecordSet
Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
Dim TS As Date

'Record in change history
DoCmd.Requery ("SelectedQry")
RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

'Qry with relevant parts
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SelectedQry", dbOpenDynaset) 
Set Connection = CurrentProject.Connection
Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet

'This is the table I wish to save data into
RecordSet.Open "SELECT * FROM [Change History]",Connection,adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rs.MoveFirst
USRID = Environ("Username")
UsrInfoSt = "NAME"

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        'This is where it should be recording the tracking data but it isn't
        With RecordSet
            .AddNew
            ![Part Number] = rs![Part Nbr]
            ![Record Identifier] = rs![Concatenate]
            ![Rep] = UsrInfoSt
            ![Time Stamp] = TS
            ![Change Point] = "End Dated"
            ![Change From] = "Open Date"
            ![Change To] = "End Dated"
            ![Part Group Nbr] = rs![Part Group Nbr]
            ![Change Cluster] = Clstr
            .Update
        End With
        UpdateClstr 'Increment Change counter Clstr
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

'These are the queries that actually move the data and it appears to be fine
SQL = "INSERT INTO [Deleted Parts] SELECT SelectedQry.* FROM SelectedQry;"
CurrentDb.Execute SQL

SQL = "UPDATE [Deleted Select Table] INNER JOIN [Deleted Parts] ON
[Deleted Select Table].Concatenate = [Deleted Parts].Concatenate SET
[Deleted Parts].[Date Deleted] = """ & Now() & """ WHERE (([Deleted
Select Table].[Select]=True));"
CurrentDb.Execute SQL

SQL = "DELETE [Part Number].* FROM [Select Table] INNER JOIN [Part
Number] ON [Select Table].Concatenate = [Part Number].Concatenate WHERE
[Select Table].[Select] = True;"
CurrentDb.Execute SQL

SQL = "UPDATE  [Deleted Select Table] INNER JOIN [Deleted Parts] ON
[Deleted Select Table].Concatenate = [Deleted Parts].Concatenate SET
[Deleted Select Table].[Select] = False WHERE ((([Deleted Select Table].
[Select])=True));"
CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```

Comment: I feel like the only reason that you wouldn't get an error message yet the code doesn't work would be because it isn't getting into your if statement.   Try  putting a message box just inside of your  `If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then` and see if it is getting there.

Comment: The message box popped up, and I had some `Debug.Print` lines inside the `With` to make sure that the data coming from rs was correct and they all worked as well.

Comment: Do you have `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` anywhere in your code --- not just in this code sample you showed us --- but in any of the code contained in this project?

Comment: Also everywhere you have `CurrentDb.Execute SQL`, change it to `CurrentDb.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError`

Comment: I do have some `DoCmd.SetWarings False` in various locations in my overall code. I also switched to `CurrentDb.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError` as you recommended. None of the SQL executions in the problem code gave me an error, but I did find an error in an unrelated portion of code, lol.